# How to reduce the verbosity of the MSBuild workflow activity?

Tags: tfs, workflow-foundation

Here is an example of what I have today:
[image]

And it remains the same regardless of the value passed to the Verbosity parameter.

Is there a way to reduce this clutter?

We are using TFS 2015.

Comment: Which TFS version do you use?

Comment: 2015 - added to the post

Answer (score 0):

In a build process that is based on the Default Template or the Upgrade Template, you can use the **Logging Verbosity** build process parameter to manage the verbosity of the information that is logged and stored.
The following table lists the Logging Verbosity values and their corresponding effects:
[image]
More details please refer this link:  [Manage Build Information and Control Verbosity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#The%20Logging%20Verbosity%20Build%20Process%20Parameter)

---

If you are using a **custom build template**. Suggest you to use minimal Verbosity When Designing a Custom Build Process Template

Users of your build process rely on verbosity filtering to reduce information overload. You can help make this filtering more effective by taking the following measures: [Best Practice: Set Verbosity as Low as Possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Hmm, I see this Verbosity argument passed to the MSBuild activity and it affects the log output of the MSBuild itself, but not the activity. Even with the minimal logging it still clutters the activity log. But the MSBuild itself does log minimally. But my problem is with the activity log.

Comment: I ran the build again with minimal verbosity. The MSBuild logs are truly minimal, as expected, but I can still see the same verbose output in the workflow log.

Comment: @mark For the activity, you may have to use custom activity to run the build just as *eldor* suggest  above https://devtfs.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/dealing-with-long-running-activities/. There is no simple parameters can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

These are basically the targets that MSBuild compiles, and as I experienced, it cannot really be controlled with the verbosity.

Our solution was to use custom activity to run the build (we have a wrapper), where we did not pass the TFS logger parameter to the MSBuild.

However in such a case you should consider that the MSBuild task can run for long time, and your custom activity should be cancellable. In this topic I can suggest to read the below article:

https://devtfs.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/dealing-with-long-running-activities/

You may also want to show the compiled targets somehow, therefore you might need to write your own custom MSBuild Logger and a UI to show the result as well.

Comment: Just another reason not to use TFS build workflows. Sigh.